# Create a new column base on existing column, but row above

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column based on an existing column, but a row above

Starting with:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:10), b=c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple"))
```

With the result looking like:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:10), b=c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple"), c=c("na", "red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "blue", "green", "yellow"))
```

Thank you for any help you are able to provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `shift` from package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df$c <- shift(df$b, 1)

df
#    a      b      c
#1   1    red   <NA>
#2   2 yellow    red
#3   3   blue yellow
#4   4  green   blue
#5   5 yellow  green
#6   6 purple yellow
#7   7   blue purple
#8   8  green   blue
#9   9 yellow  green
#10 10 purple yellow
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` this can be done with `mutate` and `lag` functions:

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, c = lag(b))

#>     a      b      c
#> 1   1    red   <NA>
#> 2   2 yellow    red
#> 3   3   blue yellow
#> 4   4  green   blue
#> 5   5 yellow  green
#> 6   6 purple yellow
#> 7   7   blue purple
#> 8   8  green   blue
#> 9   9 yellow  green
#> 10 10 purple yellow
```